# Real time FFT & IFFT with low pass filter

Tags: matlab, filtering

I am processing the signal from MPU6050. Applying FIR filter in the frequency domain and then taking IFFT to get filtered signal but getting some spikes in the output signal. Searched a lot about it and found here exit spectral leakage. Found some solutions like zero paddings and windowing but nothing is working.
Can some one take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Here is what I am getting
[image: Filtering result after IFFT]

Some zoom in
[image: Zoom in graph]

More zoom in

[image: Zoom in graph]

Compete MATLAB Code

```
close all; clear all ;clc; delete(instrfindall); 
arduino=serial('COM6','BAUD', 115200); 
fopen(arduino); 
java.lang.Thread.sleep(0.01);  % in mysec!

samples = pow2(nextpow2(5000))
sig = []; out_sig =[0];  tic;    G=0;    trying=0;  pingpong = 0;
while 1
    idn = fscanf(arduino);
    xx = str2double(idn);
    if isnan(xx)
        fclose(arduino);
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1);  % in mysec!
        fopen(arduino);
        java.lang.Thread.sleep(1);  % in mysec!
        trying  = trying + 1
        continue
    else
        sig = [sig  xx];
    end
    if length(sig)>samples - 1
        break
    end
end
fclose(arduino);
plot(sig,'g');      %---------------------------->Orginal signal <---------------------------
hold on 
PG = plot(out_sig,'k');  %---------------------------->Output signal <---------------------------
PG.YDataSource = 'out_sig';

SegmentLength = pow2(nextpow2(1000))  % Transform length to next pow of 2
Fs = SegmentLength; 

wiin = hann(64,'symmetric');
filtcoeff  = fir1(63, 20/Fs, 'low', wiin, 'scale');
firfilterimpresp = impz(filtcoeff);
filterffte = fft(firfilterimpresp,SegmentLength); % FFT of impulse response of filter/system

ChunkStart = 1;
ChunkEnd = SegmentLength;
sigblock = [];
for t = 1:samples/SegmentLength
    sigblock = sig(ChunkStart:ChunkEnd);
    blockfft = fft(sigblock,SegmentLength);
    out_sigg = real(ifft(blockfft.*filterffte'));
    out_sig = [out_sig out_sigg];

    refreshdata
    drawnow
    ChunkStart = ChunkEnd;
    ChunkEnd = ChunkEnd + SegmentLength -1 ;
end
```

Comment: Read up on "overlap add"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method. You can also just use the built in Matlab function fftfilt() that implements it

Comment: Added following code but getting same problem   DesignedFilt = designfilt('lowpassfir', 'FilterOrder', 32,'CutoffFrequency', 20, 'SampleRate', Fs);    out_sigg = fftfilt(DesignedFilt,sigblock,SegmentLength);

Answer (score 1):

The sharp peaks are actually due to segmentation and concatenation, you need to have overlapping segmentations. The peaks occur on the edges of segments mostly. In following figures I tried to show what I mean, blue curve are Hanning function coefficients. I did not understood why your application is so, but if it is essential to process your signal in segmented mode, you should consider overlapped segments. For your case each segment of signal must have 25% overlap with the next one, in other words, assuming the segment length to be $N$, if $x_{i-1}(t)$ is a segment of the signal you must have $x_i(t)$ where $x_{i-1}(0.75N : N) = x_i(0:0.25 N)$.

[image]

The following shows a 50% overlapping mode,

[image]